# Zipped File from URL to Python (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, url, gitlab, zip

I want to load a zipped from from Gitlab to my Jupyter Noteboook with following code:

```
link='https://git. ... master/data.zip'

import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve(link, "data.zip")
import zipfile
compressed_file = zipfile.ZipFile('data.zip')
csv_file = compressed_file.open('data.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
```

I could not download it, I need to get the data from the URL!

I get follwing error in Line 4 (----> 4 compressed_file = zipfile.ZipFile('data.zip'))

**BadZipFile: File is not a zip file**

What is the error in my code?

Comment: If your zip file contains only one file, you can do `pd.read_csv(link)` but it will probably not solve your problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code sample is not re-producable. Code below shows how to download a zip file from a URL and unzip it.  It's **geojson** so `json.loads()` is used, but this can be `pd.read_csv()` for CSV data.
This is effectively a three step process

- pass a URL to `requests.get()` and download chunks to local file
- inspect contents of this zip file for file within it you want to use `zfile.infolist()`
- open file handle and use it.  For your case pd.read_csv()

All standard requests and file handling independent of usage.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile
import json, io

# source geojson for country boundaries
geosrc = pd.json_normalize(requests.get("https://pkgstore.datahub.io/core/geo-countries/7/datapackage.json").json()["resources"])
fn = Path(geosrc.loc[geosrc["name"].eq("geo-countries_zip"), "path"].values[0]).name

if not Path.cwd().joinpath(fn).exists():
    r = requests.get(geosrc.loc[geosrc["name"].eq("geo-countries_zip"), "path"].values[0],stream=True,)
    with open(fn, "wb") as fd:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
            fd.write(chunk)

zfile = ZipFile(fn)
with zfile.open(zfile.infolist()[0]) as f:
    geojson = json.load(f)
```

Comment: So I have to change „json.loads()“ to „pd.read_csv()“ and than it should work for my zipped CSV?

Comment: three things: 1. need to pass URL to `requests` in this example it is https://pkgstore.datahub.io/core/geo-countries/geo-countries_zip/data/b11a931a6d3f0b0f262de2c8817361e6/geo-countries_zip.zip 2. you need to inspect `zfile.infolist()` for file you want from zip file 3. with 2, open it and pass file handle into required function,  in your case pd.read_csv()

Comment: I've updated the answer to explain it if it wasn't clear.  I could code it up if you were prepared to share your actual URL